# Group records by id

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am getting records like this returned from a stored procedure:

```
Id       FullName         Review      Rating
---------------------------------------------
1         john              sk         4.5
1         john              hhh        3.5
1         john              jhj        1.5
2         rig               www        3.5
2         rig               eee        1.5
```

This is my query which return records like above:

```
var empDetails = context.Database.SqlQuery<SearchWorkerDetail>("exec SearchWorkerDetail @param1", new SqlParameter("param1", searchKeyword) ) 
                       .Select( d => new
                                     {
                                        id = d.Id,
                                        FullName = d.FullName,
                                        Email = d.Email,
                                        ServiceDescription = d.ServiceDescription,
                                        Skills = d.Skills,
                                        Name = d.Name,
                                        r = d.Review,
                                        averagerating = d.Rating
                                     }).ToList();
```

Now I want to group the records by Id and want to select data.

Expected output:

```
SearchWorkerDetail=
    [0]:{
    Id:1
    FullName:John
    Email:john@yahoo.com
      ReviewList:
      {
         [0]: Review=sk
              rating=4.5
         [1]: Review=hhh
              rating=3.5
         [2]: Review=jhj
              rating=1.5
      }
    [1]:{
    Id:2
    FullName:rig
    Email:rig@yahoo.com
      ReviewList:
      {
         [0]: Review=www
              rating=3.5
         [1]: Review=eee
              rating=1.5
      }
    }
```

For corresponding id I want list of reviews (1 to many relation between worker and review)

My class structure:

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchWorkerDetail
{
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Skills { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Review { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Nullable<decimal> Rating { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<ReviewModel> RatingList { get; set; }
}
```

My query is like this:

```
var data = empDetails.GroupBy(m=>m.id)
                     .Select(g => new SearchWorkerDetail
                                       {
                                          id  =g.Key,
                                          FullName = g.FullName,
                                          Reviewlist =

                                        }
                                 ).ToList();
```

Here it is not allowing me to select FullName and other (eg: Email, skillDescription, Skills etc)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `FullName` property on `g` because it's a *group* not a *single object*. However you can get the `FullName` of first record in the group then create a `ReviewList` for each record in the group by using another `Select`:

```
empDetails.GroupBy(m => m.id)
    .Select(g => new SearchWorkerDetail
                 {
                     id = g.Key,
                     FullName = g.First().FullName,
                     Reviewlist= g.Select(x => new ReviewModel
                                               { 
                                                   Review = x.Review, 
                                                   rating = x.Rating
                                               }.ToList()
                 }).ToList();
```

Or you can also group by based on `FullName`:

```
empDetails.GroupBy(m => new { m.id, m.FullName })
    .Select(g => new SearchWorkerDetail
                 {
                     id = g.Key.id,
                     FullName = g.Key.FullName,    
                     /* rest is the same */
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: FullName=g.Select(t=>t.Name).FirstOrDefault():No Error

Comment: i am not getting review data

Comment: @mariapithia - Are you sure you are getting data in `empDetails`? this code should work perfectly!